# Swift: Cannot put my value into label (optional issue)

Tags: ios, swift

I have my value from Firebase but Swift doesn't want to put it in my label.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

To summarize, my database look like that:
[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9wF7.png)

I've created a standard model call ServiceModel:

```
import Foundation

class ServiceModel {

    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var pricing: String?

    init(name: String?, category: String?, pricing: String?){
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.pricing = pricing
    }
}
```

I want to display this values into a TableView, so I've created a custom cell like this (very standard too):

```
import UIKit

class SubscriptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageService: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCategory: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPricing: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And now, here is the controller of my view:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var refServices:DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var ListSub: UITableView!

    var serviceList = [ServiceModel]()

    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return serviceList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCell", for: indexPath) as! SubscriptionTableViewCell

        let service: ServiceModel

        service = serviceList[indexPath.row]

        //cell.imageService.image = UIImage(named: service.name! + ".png")
        cell.labelName?.text = service.name //ERROR HERE
        cell.labelCategory?.text = service.category
        cell.labelPricing?.text = service.pricing

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ListSub.delegate = self
        ListSub.dataSource = self

        refServices = Database.database().reference().child("Categories");

        refServices.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                self.serviceList.removeAll()

                for services in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let serviceObject = services.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let serviceName  = serviceObject?["Name"]
                    let serviceCategory  = serviceObject?["Category"]
                    let servicePricing = serviceObject?["Pricing"]
                    let service = ServiceModel(name: serviceName as! String?, category: serviceCategory as! String?, pricing: servicePricing as! String?)

                    self.serviceList.append(service)
                }

                self.ListSub.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
```

When I launch this view, I have the error mentioned earlier.
When I debug, I see that I have the right values in service.name, service.category and service.pricing

It seems that I don't correctly handle Optional values, but I cannot see what is wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Mark the line in you code where it gives you this error with a comment.

Comment: Design your data model very carefully. Unlike in Objective-C you have to take care of the types in Swift. Avoid optionals as much as possible. If a property in `ServiceModel` is supposed to have always a value declare it as non-optional. You get rid of potential crashes as well as unnecessary type checks at runtime and other boilerplate code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I've put a comment //ERROR HERE

Comment: Check if the labels are connected properly from the outlets. Check which property is `nil`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for all your comments. How am I suppose to declare non-optional value? I saw an explanations of you in StackOverflow, but I cannot apply it without error.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri You're my hero!!! I've changed labels names during my development and links were broken. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Do you think you can create an answer, like that I will mark it as Validate?

Comment: @Vomiderat it's cool. It has been asked and answered a lot of times. If possible just delete this question and upvote a question which solves this problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this function, what did you see for your service

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCell", for: indexPath) as! SubscriptionTableViewCell

    let service: ServiceModel

    //Put a breakpoint here
    service = serviceList[indexPath.row]
    //Put a breakpoint here

    //cell.imageService.image = UIImage(named: service.name! + ".png")
    cell.labelName?.text = service.name
    cell.labelCategory?.text = service.category
    cell.labelPricing?.text = service.pricing

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didn't see the Service initialization

Answer (score 0):

Potential lines to be crashed in case of optional unwrapping is this line

```
    refServices = Database.database().reference().child("Categories");
    refServices.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Try to pur breakpoint and check if `refServices` is initialised properly or make ti to be optional not using `!`

Hope this help

Ps. please remove `;` out of your Swift code :P

Comment: I think it works, cause when I put some print, i have this results:
Optional("Maestro")
Optional("Music")
Optional("360€")
Optional("Actor")
Optional("Films")
Optional("500€")

My print are like this:
print(service.name as Any)
print(service.category as Any)
print(service.pricing as Any)

PS: thanks for the ";" :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCell", for: indexPath) as! SubscriptionTableViewCell
    let service = serviceList[indexPath.row]

    // If you sure that you have to display all the info use this code
    if let name = service.name, let category = service.category, let price = service.pricing {
        cell.labelName.text = name
        // set other data also here....
    }


    // If you know any value may be empty or not exists then use this code.
    if let name = service.name {
        cell.labelName.text = name
    }

    if let category = service.category {
        cell.labelCategory.text = service
    }

    if let pricing = service.pricing {
        cell.labelPricing.text = pricing
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: The three optional bindings at the end are pointless as **both** `text` and the `ServiceModel` properties are optionals anyway.

Comment: ServiceModel properties are optional that why using optional binding

Comment: The `text` properties are optional, too. Assigning an optional to an optional will never cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your custom `UITableViewCell` with your tableView? Put this line into the `init()` function of your ViewController:

```
ListSub.register(SubscriptionTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubCell")
```

Comment: Please don't suggest optional binding in `dequeueReusableCell` lines. That's one of the few cases where forced unwrapping is very useful. The code **must not crash** if everything is connected properly. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake at once. And you must not register cells if the cells are prototype cells designed in Interface Builder.